# How to send an alert message to a friend in the same network?

Tags: networking, message, send

I would like to send some messages to my friend who is in the same network as mine, but I do not want him to confirm any password or registration. Just a pop up windows appears on his screen. Any suggestion, please? Windows Vista is my OS, however If you could provide the tips which could pass across OS Plateform like Linux to Windows, or Windows to Linux would be so great. Thanks you so much.

Comment: So more details of what you are trying to be would be helpful.  Operating system, are you using some kind of IM system?

Comment: When you say same network, do you mean the same IP subnet?

Answer (score 1):

The only built-in tool I know for Windows is the "NET SEND" command.

Comment: which is turned off by default in xp and up, i believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to do this cross-platform, take a look at the [Jabber/XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabber) protocol.  This should point you to implementations of this protocol that might meet your needs.  Unix systems have an old protocol named [talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_(software)) to do this, but windows does not support it out of the box.  There is a very old windows-specific command that can be manipulated to pop up a message box on a remote machine (but you typically won't have sufficient permissions), but for the life of me, I can't remember what it is at the moment.